# unsure if that's Vs. unsure whether that's

Tags: word-choice, whether-if

should it be 1. Our AI is unsure if that's your real name.

Or 2. Our AI is unsure whether that's your real name?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, though I would prefer *Whether*.

*Whether* implies that you are covering both options: *Is* and *Is Not*.

*If* statements can sometimes make people think that the alternative, *Is Not*, will be explicitly stated.

Since you do not intend to explicitly state the negative case, *whether* sounds better.